# Launch any app from Windows 10 Terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal

How can I launch any installed app from terminal without writing the full path?

I understand that I can launch an app using `start C:\…\…\app.exe`. Is there an equivalent that allows me to launch any app using a short form using something like `start edge`?

Comment: you need to understand the `environment varible` called `path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by their name!

Windows apps are stored in a directory named C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. It is a hidden directory by default because windows doesn't want you to play with them. First you need to enable settings in folder options to show it. Also when you click it you get that you don't have appropriate permissions to access it. So you a have to first take ownership of the folder and then assign full access ACL settings to either Users or if you are local administrator then Administrator group.

But there is still a way to launch edge from command line. You have to use `start microsoft-edge://` for this. You can also specify an URL after this. And also to launch settings app you can do `start ms-settings://`. Where your `start edge` is quite like linux terminal, where you can install packages and every GUI and CLI programs are saved to /usr/bin directory and launch them just by name.

But when you want to launch any other application rather than a windows app, then you can specify full path to launch it. Or you can add it to your PATH environment variable as @Dave.d said earlier. There are no restrictions like this.